# Multi-threading diff

Tags: diff, gnu-parallel

I'm comparing the content of two directories using the `diff` command in bash.

It uses only one thread on a multi-thread system.
Does somebody knows a way to have `diff` to use more than one cpu/thread? Using `parallel` maybe?

Comment: Yes use gnu parallel. It will launch multiple `diff`s, upto one per file, upto one per cpu. However it may not be any faster, as the bottle-neck may the the single hard-disk. (try it and see)

Comment: Have you looked at the manual?

Answer (score 4):

```
parallel diff {} ../other/dir/{} ::: *
```

Comment: This does not descend into subdirectories. Maybe adding the -r option to diff?